# Java how JVM works?

Tags: java

A Java virtual machine (JVM) is a virtual machine that enables a computer to run Java programs as well as programs written in other languages that are also compiled to Java bytecode. The JVM is detailed by a specification that formally describes what is required in a JVM implementation. Having a specification ensures interoperability of Java programs across different implementations so that program authors using the Java Development Kit (JDK) need not worry about idiosyncrasies of the underlying hardware platform.

The JVM reference implementation is developed by the OpenJDK project as open source code and includes a JIT compiler called HotSpot. The commercially supported Java releases available from Oracle are based on the OpenJDK runtime. Eclipse OpenJ9 is another open source JVM for OpenJDK.

Comment: Why would it put `3` anywhere if it's unused?

Comment: I mean the return value is unused, not the function itself. (So there's no point in loading `3` into a register.) Since the call has no side effects and you don't use the return value, it can be discarded altogether.

Comment: The compiler can tell that the function is pure (has no side-effects and doesn't touch global data), and it can see that you don't use the result. So the whole function call is removed as it has no effect. Try `return three();` instead

Comment: `int x` is also unused and will be optimized away together with the function call.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted. If you continue to vandalise the question it will be locked.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler likely optimizes this by inlining the call of `three` in `main`. Then, in effect, `main` has the statement `3;`. This statement has no observable effect, so the compiler further optimizes by removing it. Then `main` contains only `return 0;`, so the compiler generates code for that and nothing else.

When optimizing programs, a compiler is only required to consider *observable behavior*, which is, per C 2018 5.1.2.3 6, only input-output interactions, data written into files, and accesses to `volatile` objects:

> — Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
>
> — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
>
> — The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program waiting for input.

Merely putting 3 into a register would not be an observable behavior, so the compiler is not required to keep it.